# How to inject secrets to ecs task definitions using aws-cdk

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm trying to add secrets to a task definition but can't find a way to specify which key to use from the key/value in the secret.

```py
secrets = {
    "DBUSER": ecs.Secret.from_secrets_manager(
        sm.Secret.from_secret_complete_arn(
            self, 'secret-dbuser',
            'arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:accountid:secret:secret-name').secret_value_from_json('DBUSER')
        )
}

container: ecs.ContainerDefinition = task_definition.add_container(
    "reports",
    image=ecs.RepositoryImage.from_ecr_repository(
        ecr.Repository.from_repository_name(self, "container", "container"), tag=image_tag,
    ),
    memory_limit_mib=2048, logging=ecs.LogDriver.aws_logs(stream_prefix="container-"),
    secrets=secrets
)
```

secret_value_from_json returns a SecretValue which isn't what I need.
I've also tried using from_secret_manager with filed='DBUSER' but that gives me an error like this

```
Invalid request provided: Create TaskDefinition: The Systems Manager parameter name specifie
d for secret DBUSER is invalid. The parameter name can be up to 2048 characters and include the following letters and symbols: a
-zA-Z0-9_.-, (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ClientException; Request ID
```

Comment: Q: Does anything here help? [Specifying sensitive data using Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html)

Comment: @paulsm4 maybe, but this is how to do it in cloudformation - I'm loking for the way to do it with the cdk, if I use the secret:secret-name:key format it complains that `secretCompleteArn` does not appear to be complete; missing 6-character suffix

Comment: So why not provide full arn? Why did you skip those 6 random characters which are part of Secrets Manager ARN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the secret is in the same account/region, you should be able to do:

```py
secrets = {
    "DBUSER": ecs.Secret.from_secrets_manager(
        # import the secret by its name
        sm.Secret.from_secret_name_v2(self, 'secret-dbuser', '<secret-name-here>'),
        # specify the specific field
        'DBUSER'
    )
}

container: ecs.ContainerDefinition = task_definition.add_container(
    "reports",
    image=ecs.RepositoryImage.from_ecr_repository(
        ecr.Repository.from_repository_name(self, "container", "container"), tag=image_tag,
    ),
    memory_limit_mib=2048, logging=ecs.LogDriver.aws_logs(stream_prefix="container-"),
    secrets=secrets
)
```

`ecs.Secret.from_secrets_manager()` expects an `ISecret` and a `field`.

See also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/Secret.html#aws_cdk.aws_ecs.Secret.from_secrets_manager